# Check if string matches pattern without regard for characters

Tags: python, string

How can I check if a string variable matches the pattern?

Example:

```
"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
```

Where X can be a letter (upper or lower case) or number.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Check out [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: What have your tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this regular expression

```
import re
string="SAD243-SFMKD-dskl30i-DLW20a" 
if re.search(r'[\w+-]+\w$',string):
    print('Correct Format')
```

next time take care to post the code you have tried along with question